# 404 error on angular app deployed on Heroku when manually typing route

Tags: heroku, angular8

I've deployed an angular 8 application on Heroku. Its route is working fine when clicked on them, but
when typing them manually in the browser it's returning 404 error.

Please help. Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I've fixed this issue by modifying server.js code:

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/project-folder'));
// Start the app by listening on the default
// Heroku port

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/project-folder');
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
==============================================
**Modified code is below which fixed the issue:**
===========================================
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/project-folder'));
// Start the app by listening on the default
// Heroku port

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/project-folder/index.html');
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```